# How to ensure dependencies on host are removed when we remove a docker container

Tags: docker

I created a docker container and have an application running inside it. I created a second docker container (on the same host) with the same application running inside it. I need to create a few more containers this way. However, when I remove a container, I need to ensure that the dependencies it creates on the host are completely removed. How could this be achieved ?

Thanks,

Comment: by that I mean I wish to remove any mapping (-v ) that exists between the host and the container

Comment: Why do you use `-v` in the first place then? This option is for **persistent** storage. If you don't need persistent storage, why would you use it?!

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the documentation of the [docker rm](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/rm/) command:

> Usage:  docker rm [OPTIONS] CONTAINER [CONTAINER...]
>
> Remove one or more containers
>
> Options:
>   -f, --force     Force the removal of a running container (uses SIGKILL)
>         --help      Print usage
>   -l, --link      Remove the specified link
>   -v, --volumes   Remove the volumes associated with the container

So use the "-v" option

---

### Update

You can also use this command to cleanup volumes with no associated containers.

```
docker volume rm $(docker volume ls -qf dangling=true)
```

Credit: [sceada](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4564449/sceada)